# making code reusable with extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I tried to create such extension method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CommonLibs.CommonClasses.Extensions
{
    public static class EnumerableExt
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, object> keyGroup)
        {
            return from x in collection group x by keyGroup into grp select grp.First();
        }
    }
}
```

but if I want to use it like this :

```
public class PricingCoefficient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double FootageFrom { get; set; }
    public double? FootageTo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Coefficient { get; set; }
}

pricingCoefficients.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Coefficient, x.FootageFrom, x.FootageTo });
```

it gives me error:

> Error 30  The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TKey' in the generic type or method
>   'CommonLibs.CommonClasses.EnumerableExtensions.DistinctBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.IEquatable'.

Any idea how to make this an extension method?

thanks

Comment: What is `pricingCoefficients`'s type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another type `T2`, a keyselector like `Func<T, T2> keyGroup` and call it as `keyGroup(x)`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy2<T,T2>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, T2> keyGroup)
{
    return from x in collection group x by keyGroup(x) into grp select grp.First();
}
```

Comment: it works, but I dont understand it. Can you please give me some quick explanation? thanks :)

Comment: @JohnSmith see `group x by keyGroup(x)` you don't want to compare the *delegates* instead the return value of it.

Comment: Yes, but for what reason I need to add T2 instead of object?

Comment: @JohnSmith it's strange that using `object` works for me, there isn't any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
                                           Func<T, object> keyGroup) {
    return from x in collection group x by keyGroup(x) into grp select grp.First();
}
```

**NOTE**: I couldn't reproduce your problem, using `keyGroup` (without `(x)` doesn't throw any exception, it's just **wrong** to produce the correct result of `DistinctBy`.